# Segmentation fault with sscanf on big number

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am fairly new in C and I'm  trying to read a large file (>30m lines) line by line and store some values of each line into an array. The format of the input file is:

```
1. inode    100660 uid  66322 gid  66068 bytes       5848 blks        128
2. inode    100662 uid  66492 gid  66076 bytes        159 blks          0
3. inode    100647 uid  66419 gid  66068 bytes        235 blks          0
4. inode 100663302 uid  66199 gid  66068 bytes        131 blks          0
5. inode 100663311 uid  66199 gid  66068 bytes        134 blks          0
```

And this is my code:

```
void loadArrayFromFile(char * filename) {
long bytesArray[380000000];
FILE * myfile;
myfile = fopen(filename, "r");
char line[1024];
char inodeText[10];
long int inode = 0;
int mybytes = 0;

if(myfile == NULL) {
    printf("No file found \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), myfile)) {
    int x = (sscanf(line, "%s %ld %*s %*d %*s %*d %*[bytes] %d %*[^\n]", inodeText, &inode, &mybytes));
    if(x > 1) {
        bytesArray[inode] = mybytes;
    }
}
```

This **code works fine for the first 3 lines**, however when it reaches line 4 I get a Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error. I suspect it has something to do with the inode value being too large to store into an int even though the max value an int can store is 2147483647. Can anyone help me out as to what the issue is?

Comment: `inodeText` buffer is only 10 bytes long. Is it enough?

Comment: longest word i can see is `bytes` i think it is

Comment: Where is `bytesArray` defined?

Comment: Are the `1.` and `2.` etc in the input example part of the text being scanned? If they are, then the second format spec should be `%s`.

Comment: @dbush bytesArray is defined outside this method's scope. I have just added it to the code block for readibility. The line numbers are not part of the file, I only added them to call out the lines easier. inodeText is only meant to contain the string 'inode' so yes that buffer is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the inode number as the index `bytesArray`.  You don't show how big this array is, but I'm betting it's much smaller than 100663302.  So you're writing past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Rather than using the inode number as an index, use a `struct` which contains both the inode number and the file size, and use an array of those along with a count of the element in the array.

```
struct entry {
    int inode;
    int nbytes;
};

struct entry entryArray[10];   // assuming there are no more than 10 lines in the file
int arrayLen = 0;

...

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), myfile)) {
    int x = (sscanf(line, "%s %ld %*s %*d %*s %*d %*[bytes] %d %*[^\n]", inodeText, &inode, &mybytes));
    if(x > 1) {
        entryArray[arrayLen].inode = inode;
        entryArray[arrayLen].nbytes = mybytes;
        arrayLen++;
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I have missed this. Such an easy fix. Thank you!

Comment: Iam wondering why we can pass more specifiers than variables and cant find it anywhere. Could you explain it in a few rows or post some link?

Comment: but in the code `long bytesArray[380000000];` should fit (unless stack explodes first :))

Comment: @FilipKočica-- you can't: ["If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p2). But the `*` suppresses assignment.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre the inode on line 4 is 100m but the the bytesArray is only initialized for 38m values therefore causing a segmentation fault!

Comment: Hmm can someone point out why my question has a negative rating? I am new to Stack Overflow so there are still some conventions I'd like to learn and follow.

Comment: that's because this is a "why isn't this code working" kind of question, probably with poor "replay value" for others. but that's not a very bad question either. some questions get 5 to 10 downvotes. Not yours.